# Why does this stop after the first 3 numbers with a mips tree traversal?

Tags: assembly, tree, mips, traversal

The tree traversal routine takes in 3 arguments, the first node, the processing function and the order constant.

```
traverse_tree:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-8
    sw      $ra,0($sp)
    sw      $a0,4($sp)

    beq     $a0,$zero,done
    move    $t3,$a2
    move    $t2,$a1
    move    $t0,$a0
    li      $t1,PRE_ORDER
    beq     $t3,$t1,preorder
    li      $t1,IN_ORDER
    beq     $t3,$t1,inorder
    li      $t1,POST_ORDER
    beq     $t3,$t1,postorder

 preorder:

    jalr    $t2
    lw      $a0,4($t0)
    jal     traverse_tree
    lw      $a0,8($t0)
    jal     traverse_tree
    jal     done


inorder:
    lw      $a0,4($t0)
    jal     traverse_tree
    move    $a0,$t0
    jalr    $t2
    lw      $a0,8($t0)
    jal     traverse_tree
    jal     done

 postorder:
    lw      $a0,4($t0)
    jal     traverse_tree
    lw      $a0,8($t0)
    jal     traverse_tree
    move    $a0,$t0
    jalr    $t2
    jal     done


done:
    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    lw      $a0,4($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,8
    jr      $ra
```

The program stops when it hits the third element.  Im pretty sure this element is a node with both leaves null.

Comment: Your `$t0` is getting clobbered with each `jal traverse_tree` -- after you return from it, `$t0` won't be the same. Try pushing `$t0` as well at the start (and pop it at the end).

Answer (score 0):

What Jeff said. Specifically, you should use `s0` over `t0`, because temporary variables have no assurance of not being overwritten, however `s*` registers are "promised" to be saved and restored when you call a function. You yourself need to add 4 more bytes to the stack and save and restore `s0` if you don't want your own function to overwrite it every call.